# ThreadLocal - Is it required if we are setting the value in constructor?

Tags: java, thread-local

I have a class, MyThread which implements Callable <String>. The class has a constructor which takes  parameters like a blockingqueue and others. In my main class, I instantiate this class, MyThread,  with a new blocking queue and other parameters. Also, I maintain two maps, one to keep MyThread reference with one of unique parameter as key and other to keep blocking queue reference with the same unique key.

During the process, I get this blocking queue from the hashmap, add my custom message and take the corresponding MyThread instance and submit to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor (Spring version).

As far as I understand, each thread should get its own copy of values (like blocking queue etc), as am passing them during the construction and creating a thread later using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(myThreadObj). I was just wondering if someone could confirm if that is true OR whether I am required to use ThreadLocal in this scenario. So far with the testing, I did not encounter problem, but then I am yet to do the load testing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have effectively reinvented ThreadLocal.  Enjoy!